# python - Plotting implicit function f(x,y) = 0, where x,y undergo matrix multiplication

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, implicit

As the implicit function where 'A' is an n*2 matrix

```
0 = np.dot((x,y),A)
```

0 = xA<sub>11</sub> yA<sub>12</sub>

0 = xA<sub>21</sub> yA<sub>22</sub>

...

0 = xA<sub>n1</sub> yA<sub>n2</sub>

Is it possible, via matplotlib or other means, to plot all the lines on the same plot without a large loop?

Comment: `0 = np.dot((x,y),A)` is not valid Python code. Could you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `n*2` matrix `A`, for each row `i` a line is defined by `A[i,0]*x + A[i,1]*y == 0`. This means `0,0` always lies on the line, as well as the point `x=A[i,1],y=-A[i,0]`. Multiplying with any value, e.g. by normalizing will again give points on the line.

The following code shows 3 ways to visualize these lines:

- Some line segments cut by a circle, together with `x=A[i,1],y=-A[i,0]` and `x=-A[i,1],y=A[i,0]`.
- The same segments extended till the plot's border.
- Just some end points on a circle.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

n = 10
radius = 20
A = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (n, 2))
B = A / norm(A, axis=1, keepdims=True) * radius # normalize and put on a circle with given radius
lines = np.dstack([B[:, 1], -B[:, 0], -B[:, 1], B[:, 0]]).reshape(-1, 2, 2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(14, 4))
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
for ax in axes[:2]:
    lc = LineCollection(lines, colors='blue', linewidths=2)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    if ax == axes[0]:
        ax.scatter(A[:, 1], -A[:, 0], color='crimson')
        ax.scatter(-A[:, 1], A[:, 0], color='crimson')
    elif ax == axes[1]:
        ax.set_xlim(-radius / 2, radius / 2)
        ax.set_ylim(-radius / 2, radius / 2)
for k in range(2):
    axes[2].scatter(lines[:, k, 0], lines[:, k, 1], color='crimson')
axes[0].set_title('lines in circle and dots')
axes[1].set_title('lines till border')
axes[2].set_title('dots on circle')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]